# Do any 3D file formats allow arbitrary metadata?

Tags: 3d, metadata, file-format

I have essentially this question:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72760/how-can-i-store-game-metadata-in-a-png-file

…in 3D.

Are there any 3D file formats which allow arbitrary metadata?

(By "allow" I mean: are specced to parse correctly even when custom properties are included, or at least are unlikely to break or cause trouble when they are.)